# Python append dataframe such that only columns remain the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes in python pandas:

A:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
0 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
```

B:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
1 0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
```

C:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
2 0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I want to concatenate them together such that the column titles remain the same while row index and values get appended so the new dataframe is:

df:

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
0 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
1 0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
2 0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

I have tried using [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) and [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) but none seem to be fulfilling the output I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions?

Here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.concat([A,B,C], ignore_index=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is a plain vanilla concat  `pd.concat([A, B, C])`

Comment: Ah yes @piRSquared Thats right! Answer it so I can mark as correct. The more complicated approaches didn't work, it did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a plain vanilla concat

```
pd.concat([A, B, C])

     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
0 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
1 0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
2 0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple `pd.concat` will just do the work, you over complicated the task a little bit:

```
pd.concat([A,B,C], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: For this problem, the last 2 params are redundant, but props for being explicit :)

Comment: If `B` and `C` do have the correct index, then it is redundant, but I always want it to be clear when I'm joining. :)